# PhoneGap - the options undefined error/warning on create

Tags: android, cordova, frameworks, phonegap-build

I have installed the latest version of Phonegap (v3.x) using Node and have run the following via the command line

```
$ phonegap create my-app
```

This displays the following:

```
[phonegap] the options undefined C:\AndroidProjects\my-app com.phonegap.helloworld HelloWorld
[phonegap] created project at C:\AndroidProjects\my-app
```

Even when I create another app and add the options similar to that above i get the same message? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the cordova cli

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Then run

```
cordova create new_directory_name com.example.hello Hello\ World
```

This will create a new directory "new_directory_name" and generate a app with id "com.example.hello" and title "Hello World" (you may need to escape the space between Hello and world some other way. The \ works on *nix but I see you are on windows.)

Next cd into the new dir and run

```
cd new_directory_name
cordova platforms add android
```

After this all phonegap commands should simply work.

Comment: whats the difference between cordova & phonegap.. i'm a little confused by it?
Will I have any issues have cordova/phonegap together?

Comment: Here is the long version: http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/

Comment: The short version: Phonegap uses cordova (now opensource under an apache licence) for doing most of the work. 
Infact cordova is more convenient to use for local development. Phonegap provides a way to use build.phonegap.com which is a build platform in the cloud that allows you to build for iOS/windows etc without having all the dependencies installed.